# C# Textbox not populating when button is not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, visibility

I am having an odd reaction to hiding a button.  On the form there is a text box and a button next to it.  When the user clicks the button, the textbox is populated with the next available job number.  After the button is pressed and the number in the box, I want the button to disappear, so I have the following code:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtJobNum.Text))
            {
                btnGetJobNumber.Enabled = false;
                txtJobNum.Enabled = false;
                btnGetJobNumber.Visible = false;
                txtJobNum.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("width", "157px");
            }
```

This makes the button no visible and not clickable, however the number does not appear in the box.  It is only when I comment out the bottom two lines that the number will show and the button visible, but not clickable:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtJobNum.Text))
            {
                btnGetJobNumber.Enabled = false;
                txtJobNum.Enabled = false;
                //btnGetJobNumber.Visible = false;
                //txtJobNum.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("width", "157px");
            }
```

Pretty much how do I get the button to disappear once a number is populated?  Because my assumption that `btnGetJobNumber.Visible = false;` would do it is not right.  As long as that line is commented out it works, if I uncomment it, nothing I do makes it right.  This is in C# ASP.NET

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume this is an asp.net question,right?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry.  I will update.

Comment: "`After ... the number in the box`" and "`if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtJobNum.Text))`" - so which is it?